# "Announce the time" in Date & Time preference pane does not work

Tags: macos, system-settings

I have enabled "Announce the time" In the Date & Time Preference Pane. However, no announcement happens. It used to happen and then stopped some time ago.

Mac OS: 10.14.6 Mojave

Any suggestions as to what I can try and do? Any property that I can set using command line to make it work.

[image]

Comment: Is the volume correct? The one in "customise voice" beside it ?

Comment: Did you use your password before you changed the setting in "Date and Time".

Comment: @ankii Yes - volume is on. I can hear the voice when I play sample. The laptop sound is on.

Comment: @jmh - yes used the password to change the setting. Wonder what else can be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

For what it is worth, it appeared to me that my Speech settings in Accessibility Preference Pane were corrupted somehow. If I played any voice in Speech section of Accessibility Preference Pane, my System Preferences application would hang.

I ran this command in the terminal `tccutil reset Accessibility` and restarted the computer.

Speech module started working.

I had to reenable permissions to applications that required Accessibility access under Preference Pane - Security & Privacy - Accessibility.

Hope this helps anyone else who has this problem. I am no expert so perhaps others can chime in on the underlying details as to why `tccutil reset Accessibility` worked to address my speech preference pane.